# Update Zend OPcache PHP 8

Tags: php, plesk

i have issue with my Plesk Server . I have installed Ubuntu and Plesk new Version and PHP 8.2 (Website Say PHP 8.2 is still running)  but now it make me Crazy...

php artisan migrate - Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17.

```
 php -v
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2023 13:29:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

How can i Update to PHP 8.X

Answer (score 1):

You probably have more than one PHP version installed and the default is 7.2.

You need to find where the PHP 8.2 is located and change your php artisan command to use this version.

```
path/to/your/php/8.2/bin/php artisan migrate
```

If you dont know where it is installed, you can use this snippet at some php file in you website.

```php
<?php
echo PHP_BINARY;
```

and it will print the path to the PHP that is being used by you site.